# Browser adds extra space in indented HTML

Tags: html, css, anchor

Having this indented HTML code:

`<a href="">
    <img src="img/wordpress-logo.svg">
</a>`

As you can see in the image below the browser adds some extra space that created that ugly hyphen.

[image]

If I remove the spaces however and keep the HTML code in one line:

`<a href=""><img src="img/wordpress-logo.svg"></a>`

The problem disapear as you ca see in the image below:

[image]

Why that hapens? How can I solve that problem since I want to keep all HTML code indented.

(p.s. if you have a better title for this question let me know please, thanks)

Comment: are you using any css?

Comment: Why? Because inline elements are sensitive to white space in the HTML.

Comment: There's no problem and no "extra space added". If you don't want a space then don't have one in your code...

Comment: That's not an _"ugly hyphen"_... that is the default _underline_ of the anchor tag that's extending to your whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
a img {
    text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: FYI:  The browser usually underlines anchor tags.   This stops that from happening.

Comment: Try to explain what happens, not giving only the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="imagelink" href="">
    <img src="img/wordpress-logo.svg">
</a>
```

This is sensitive to white space and will generate a space. To remove the space, you could indeed change the code to what you did. But if you just want to make the line dissapear, consider using some css.

```
a.imagelink { text-decoration: none; }
```

This will solve the visuals, but the space will remain. I posted a simular question about generated whitespace. [view here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770789/html-a-tag-adds-whitespace/27771046)

```
<a href=""><img src="img/wordpress-logo.svg"></a>
```